# Is there a way to import debug keystore in Android?

Tags: android

We are using Android Studio and we are developing an app using the default keystore.  The application is already being used while in development so all clients already have data in their devices.

We now would like to use an actual keystore. However, creating a new one would mean the clients cannot update the application - they would have to reinstall the application which means that they would lose existing data.  Is there a way to go around this?  Or can we import the existing keystore for release?

Comment: I don't know a way, unless you implement some export/import functionality. Tip for next time: use the alpha test features of play store and sign with the release key from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored in ~/.android/debug.keystore.
On Windows, this will be something like C:\Users\Username.android\debug.keystore

However, I would advise not to do this, as the debug keys have an early expiration (at least they did with Eclipse, I haven't been able to find anything about Android Studio). Once this date is reached, there will be no option but to create a new key. It's definitely messy, but it'll be easier to clean up now rather than in a years time when you'll have even more users.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Temporarily, i copied debug.keystore, default.keyset and adbkey from that folder you mentioned so we can build an apk from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the existing keystore itself. While generating the signed apk, You can provide the path to that keystore, keystore password, key alias and key password. This is the only way with which you can generate an updated version of the existing apk.